# gradle project sync failed basic functionality will not work properly in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new in programming of android I tried to install android studio I checked this problem ,I changed the directory of JDK (File-Project Structer) to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141` but still have this problem on my android studio 3.0 preview 
You can see the problem on this image

[image]

I hope you will help me

Answer (score 0):

change distribution url which is in **Gradle script->gradle-wrapper.properties** like below and try.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: but I have https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0.2-all.zip

Comment: i think it's this the last version gradle 4.0.2 and android plugin version 3.0.0-alpha7

Answer (score 0):

Download all required sdk,sdk-tools.then rebuild your project..Hope this helpful!